# survival analysis with two levels of censoring

Tags: survival-analysis

I'm trying to figure out this problem from Applied Survival Analysis by Hosmer, Lemeshow, and May, 2nd edition. Chapter 7, #3

> In the GBCS data, does hormone use improve survival after cancer recurrence, controlling for tumor grade and size?

The data information can be seen [here](https://www.umass.edu/statdata/statdata/data/gbcs.txt)

I am confused about how to handle the data. There are two censoring variables: recurrence and death. I am not sure how to handle the subjects who do not have recurrence.

Comment: Being about statistics rather than programming, this question is better suited for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: In the meantime, this is how I'd think about it. You want to model overall survival _after_ recurrence, which requires recurrence, right? So you'll likely only want to consider subjects who have recurrence (`censrec`=1). Then the only censoring you need to worry about is `censdead`.

Answer (score 0):

The example defines TWO separate time-to-event distributions:
1. Time to recurrence
2. Time to death (i.e. survival)

Assuming #2 starts at the same time as #1, you should first subset the data so only patients who have a recurrence are included and then define a new time-to-event variable whose time is survtime-rectime and whose flag is simply censdead.  This gives you time from recurrence to death.